# error in codeigniter Message: Call to a member function row() on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter

I have been working on a CodeIgniter project and when I send the data to the view called - merchant_registration as an array

controller

```
 function Merchant_Registration($para1 = '', $para2 = '') {

        if (!$this->crud_model->admin_permission('report')) {
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/admin');
        }
        if ($para1 == 'edit') {

            $page_data['vendor_data'] = $this->db->get_where('vendor', array(
                        'vendor_id' => $para2
                    ))->result_array();
            $this->load->view('back/admin/merchant_edit', $page_data);
        } elseif ($para1 == 'update') {
            $page_data['status'] = $this->input->post('status');
            $this->db->where('vendor_id', $para2);
            $this->db->update('vendor', $page_data);
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/admin/Merchant_Registration/', 'refresh');
            recache();
        } else {
            $this->db->order_by('vendor_id', 'ased');
            $create_timestamp = $this->input->post("create_timestamp");  
            $status = $this->input->post("status");
//search query
//change the dates to the proper column 
//and find the package column and 
            //$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d"', $create_timestamp);
            $page_data['query'] = $this->db->query("select * from vendor where create_timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP($create_timestamp) and  create_timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP($create_timestamp)  or status like '%$status%'")->result_array();
            $page_data['page_name'] = "Merchant_Registration";
            $this->load->view('back/index', $page_data);
        }
    }
```

It shows this error:

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function row() on a non-object

Filename: back/index.php

Line Number: 5

Backtrace:

index file

```
<?php
    $system_name     =  $this->db->get_where('general_settings',array('type' => 'system_name'))->row()->value;
    $system_title    =  $this->db->get_where('general_settings',array('type' => 'system_title'))->row()->value;
?>
<?php include 'includes_top.php'; ?>
<body onbeforeunload="HandleBackFunctionality()">
    <div id="container" class="effect mainnav-lg">
        <!--NAVBAR-->
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
        <!--END NAVBAR-->
        <div class="boxed" id="fol">
            <!--CONTENT CONTAINER-->
            <div>
            <?php
            include $this->session->userdata('title').'/'.$page_name.'.php' ?>
            </div>
            <!--END CONTENT CONTAINER-->

            <!--MAIN NAVIGATION-->
            <?php include $this->session->userdata('title').'/navigation.php' ?>
            <!--END MAIN NAVIGATION-->

        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'script_texts.php'; ?>
        <!-- END FOOTER -->
        <!-- SCROLL TOP BUTTON -->
        <button id="scroll-top" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">
        </i></button>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF CONTAINER -->

    <!-- SETTINGS - DEMO PURPOSE ONLY -->   
<?php include 'includes_bottom.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Just a note: When loading views you can use codeigniter load view http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html and also use models for and thing you need to get from database where etc http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: If you are using a MVC framework,you should follow it. Regarding your question,its because your query has no result. `$system_title    =  $this->db->get_where('general_settings',array('type' => 'system_title'))->row()->value;`. So make sure you are getting the results before using its values

Answer (score 0):

i figured  it out i was using query builder and active record at the same time